# The TAB doesn't go into the ActiveX control embedded on my win form

Tags: c#, winforms, com, activex

My co-worker created a Qt widget under Linux which he wrapped into an ActiveX control just so I can use it in my Win application UI. I registered and added that ActiveX control in my Visual Studio toolbox and added onto my win form.

Everything is fine, but when launching my form and clicking TAB it passes the focus to the ActiveX control and then to other controls on the win form however the TAB doesn't go into the ActiveX control to do tab-stop within the ActiveX control, which itself consists of some other controls.

How, can I make the tab-stop to happen within the ActiveX control so I can tab from control to control within the ActiveX control as well? Is there any known way?

Comment: What happens to keystrokes is negotiated between the AxHost wrapper and the control.  You need to look at what the control's  IOleInPlaceActiveObject::TranslateAccelerator() implementation function does, presumably it says "all your base are belong to us" regardless of the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want a button or some element on your form to be effected by pressing TAB just add `this.MyButton.TabStop = false;` to your Designer of that specific form. All it does is disable (in this case "MyButton") to be selected by pressing TAB.
I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Christoph, I guess you didn't get my question. ActiveX control is sitting on my WinForm. All I need the TAB to work within the ActiveX control as well since there are other UI controls in that ActiveX control.

Comment: Did you make sure that `this.MyButton.TabStop` is set to `true` for your controls in your ActiveX control?

Comment: It's a Qt widget wrapped into ActiveX control for use under Windows. The TAB works perfectly under Linux and traverses through all the controls in the widget.

Comment: Do you want the TAB to **only** select controls of your ActiveC control?

Comment: Ideally both, and on the form and on the ActiveX control.